# WebView didn't render after reload

Tags: android, android-webview

In my code, webview is recycled to reuse after detach to window.

But when I reuse my webview to load the second page, nothing is rendered.

What's the problem, only occur in some phones, not every phone.

Comment: any sample code ?

Comment: Share the part of your code .

Comment: Be specific about 1: `only occur in some phones` which phone is and which phone not. 2: how do you `recycled to reuse` your web view. 3: what is the `second page` actually.

Comment: 1. only occur in Huawei mate 9

Comment: 2 remove webview from parent and store it when detach to window, get the stored webview when webview is used.

Comment: 3. At first, I load a url, then I close this webview, webview is recycled. Then I open another url, this webview is reused, it's used to load another url. But nothing loads. The url is 'about:blank'

Answer (score 0):

It seems only chrome 61 has this problem. Chrome 63 or chrome below 61 doesn't has this problem.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=740544&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=